# Horizontal Nav with Overhanging Logo

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, nav

**Solution:** http://jsfiddle.net/wXjj8/898/

I will explain my question through two separate JSFiddles...

**Please expand the result panes to see the desired result.**

I am trying to show a menu aligned like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wXjj8/899/

[image]

With a logo (grey circle) "overhanging" in the middle like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wXjj8/898/

[image]

As you can see, when I add the logo in the menu aligns below the black menu bar.

CSS:

```
.menu {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:120px;
    background-color:black;
    z-index:100;
}

.navigation{  
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav2 {
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 80%;
}
#nav { 
    text-align: center; 
}
#nav li {
    list-style: none; 
    display: inline-block; 
}
#nav a {
    color: #3297FD; 
    display: block; 
    font-family:arial; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 9px 18px 9px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}
#nav a:hover {
    background-color: #2D89E5; 
    color: #fff; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div id="nav2">
        <ul id='nav' class="navigation">
            <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
            <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/POe3phs.png"/></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for any and all tips!

Comment: where the circle must be located?

Comment: @MatteoRubini I’m assuming in the center as in http://jsfiddle.net/wXjj8/898/.

Comment: I would like it hanging partially below the black bar like in fiddle # 2 but the menu aligned like Fiddle #1

Comment: like.. this? http://jsfiddle.net/wXjj8/901/ or more horizontal centered?

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish this layout: jsfiddle.net/wXjj8/898  with the menu aligned vertically like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wXjj8/899/

Comment: @MatteoRubini it should be in the center. Expand the Result part in the second JSFiddle to see the full layout.

Comment: Maybe it is not rendering correctly, here is where I want the logo placement: http://imgur.com/wnPLj28 
Here is where I want the menu placement: http://imgur.com/48LJkej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two blocks for `#nav li` and `#nav a` should roughly achieve your desired result:

```
#nav li {
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
}
#nav a {
    color: #3297FD; 
    display: block; 
    font-family:arial; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    margin-top:52px;
    padding: 9px 18px 9px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Basically declaring `vertical-align:top;` to all list items and `margin-top:52px;` on all links for positioning.

You can also do this with a class name by adding a class name to all your “MENU” links and refering to that in the CSS instead of `#nav a`. This is useful if you want to link the circle in the middle as well.

Two other things:

- Don’t forget to wrap your `img` into a `li`—the markup in your question is different from the JSFiddle
- Add an `alt=""` tag to the `img` element

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be fixed with setting `vertical-align` property.

```
#nav li {
    vertical-align: middle; /*add this line*/
}
```

Yep, simply like that.

**Updated demo** http://jsfiddle.net/wXjj8/903/

The other problem is the `<img>` is missing `<li>` container on OP's JSFIDDLE.